# How can I get sqlite error code from Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt4

I use sqlite database in my Qt program.

```
QSqlDatabase db;
db = QsqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
```

When I can not get data from sqlite `db.lastError()` function always return same thing

```
QSqlError(-1, "Driver not Loaded", "Driver not loaded")
```

How can I get [sqlite error codes](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) from Qt?

upd1:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec(QString("select NAME from PEOPLE where AGE=%1").arg(age));
if(query.next())
{
}
else
{
    //check for sqlite error
}
```

Comment: *When* and *where* do you check for errors? Can you please show a little more code? Also, after "adding" the database, have you checked that [`isValid`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqldatabase.html#isValid) returns `true`?

Comment: Have you checked http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlerror.html#number ?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I check `isValid` return `true`.

Comment: @LaszloPapp it returns always -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do with the Qt API itself is the following method:

> [int QSqlError::number() const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlerror.html#number)
>
> Returns the database-specific error number, or -1 if it cannot be determined.

See how the error codes from sqlite are handled in the driver codebase itself:

https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/eb5c0f4b1266702c016b032e281bb92a3a642da6:src/sql/drivers/sqlite/qsql_sqlite.cpp#L324

You can see that the corresponding [QSqlError constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlerror.html#QSqlError) is used for that with passing the low-level error code to it as the last argument which you can obtain with the aforementioned method.

As you can see, it is not handling all the low-level errors similarly, but there is a default switch case in there for the rest. Even in the latter case, the errors are passed to the constructor.

You need to be aware of that, oftentimes, it cannot determine the exact low-level error in which case it will return -1 as per documentation.

Putting this into practice, you would be writing something like this:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec(QString("select NAME from PEOPLE where AGE=%1").arg(age));
if (query.next())
{
} else {
    qDebug() << "SqLite error:" << query.lastError().text() << ", SqLite error code:" << query.lastError().number();
}
```